# How quickly do larvae spawn in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

When I play Starcraft 2 as the zerg I always lose track of my larvae while fighting battles or exploring.
I was wondering if anyone knew exactly how many seconds it takes for a larva to spawn.

Comment: can only find spawn times for the first starcraft might just have to time it.

Comment: In the original StarCraft, it seemed like larva spawn rate was increased when you upgraded your hatchery as well.

Answer (score 17):

By default it is **15 seconds** on hatchery,lair and hive(it stays same).

Depending on gameplay speed:

- slower = 24.9s
- slow = 18.8s
- normal = 15.0s
- fast = 12.5s
- faster = 10.9s

Note: The queen's "spawn larva" has a 40s cooldown and spawns additional 4 larvae,but the building wont start producing more larvae until the number of them falls under 3 for that building.

Max number of larvae available for one building is 19.

Comment: * This is in-game time, most people play at "Faster" which accelerates this. Activate your in-game clock to see "game time".

Comment: @resorath yay faster

Comment: edited by calculating game time speeds.Not sure why it is not same as yours if you played on "faster".

Comment: Another factoid is that each Hatchery has a maximum number of larvae it will support. I believe this is 12. Once the max is hit, no more will spawn. If you morph some of those 12, I am not sure if another larva spawns immediately, after 15 seconds, or on some other clock.

Comment: its 19 but still not sure when they start producing more larvae when you have more than 3.

Answer (score 2):

I timed it myself from a beginning game I stared a stopwatch at the same moment i qued morphing a drone and stopped the watch as soon as i saw a Larva pop up. The time i got was 13 seconds i did it a few times and was off by roughly .1 to .2 seconds each time because of my reaction time of course.

Comment: When people ask questions about game timings, it's always referring to the in-game timer, not "real" time. Nobody uses a stopwatch during an actual game :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about [Spawn Larva](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Spawn_Larva) Queen ability:

- [Spawn Larva](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Spawn_Larva) takes 40 in-game seconds.
- According do [game-to-normal-time relations](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Game_Speed) on "faster" it 72.5%

So: 40 s * 0.725 = *29 s*